# Highlight current date in react Gantt timeline

Tags: reactjs, gantt-chart

I am using react-gantt timeline package, I don't know how to indicate current date in react gant timeline.
I am looking for a vertical bar to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom TimelineMarkers

```
import Timeline, {
  TimelineMarkers,
  CustomMarker,
  TodayMarker,
  CursorMarker
} from 'react-calendar-timeline'

<Timeline>
  <TimelineMarkers>
    <TodayMarker />
    <CustomMarker date={Date.now()} />
    <CustomMarker date={tomorrow}>
      {/* custom renderer for this marker */}
      {({ styles, date }) => {
        const customStyles = {
          ...styles,
          backgroundColor: 'deeppink',
          width: '4px'
        }
        return <div style={customStyles} onClick={someCustomHandler} />
      }}
    </CustomMarker>
    <CursorMarker />
  </TimelineMarkers>
</Timeline>
```